# Error Message "Use The New Keyword To Create An Object Instance"

Tags: .net, vb.net, constructor, instance

I keep having error message at `ArrayGroup(count).dateDate = valueListString(0)`, have no idea what's wrong with the code below, please help.

```
Structure dataAttribute
    Dim dateDate As Date
    Dim timeString As String
    Dim volString As String
    Dim openString As String
    Dim closeString As String
    Dim minString As String
    Dim maxString As String
End Structure

Private ArrayGroup() As dataAttribute

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     Handles Button1.Click
    Dim currencyString As String
    Dim valueListString() As String

    currencyString = dataTextFieldParser.ReadToEnd
    RichTextBox1.Text = currencyString

    strArr = currencyString.Split(Environment.NewLine)

    For count = 1 To strArr.Length - 1
        valueListString = strArr(count).Split(";")

        ArrayGroup(count).dateDate = valueListString(0)
        ArrayGroup(count).timeString = valueListString(1)
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: What's `ArrayGroup`? How is it defined and initialized?

Comment: Have added the defination of ArrayGroup to the code, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayGroup` is `Nothing`.

the line

```
Private ArrayGroup() As dataAttribute
```

does not assign a value to `ArrayGroup` so it is not instantiated and you'll get the normal with block error when you try to use it.

you probably want to change the end of your function to something like.

```
    Redim ArrayGroup(strArr.Length - 1) As dataAttribute


    For count = 1 To strArr.Length - 1
         valueListString = strArr(count).Split(";")

          ArrayGroup(count).dateDate = valueListString(0)         
          ArrayGroup(count).timeString = valueListString(1)     
    Next
End Sub
```

Note the `ReDim`. I'm not sure if you need the `As`.

Answer (score 0):

the ArrayGroup probably does actually have items in it.

so before the line `ArrayGroup(count).dateDate = valueListString(0)` try adding to the array

```
ArrayGroup(count) = New ... what ever type should be in the array...
```

Comment: I tried to add "ArrayGroup(count) = New dataAttribute"  before the line "ArrayGroup(count).dateDate = valueListString(0)" but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear that you have dimensioned you array:

Try

> ReDim ArrayGroup(0)

Have a look at [`ReDim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and `ReDim Preserve`

```
Private ArrayGroup() As dataAttribute
```

Just declares that ArrayGroup is an array of type dataAttribute but does not specify how many members are in it.